# prevent whitespace in input field in ant-design

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have already set whitespace to true, it is working only when we start with space. unfortutely this kind of format doesn't work [*** *** *****].
What I expect password to this format [***********] .

[whitespace:true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4rHs.png)

Thank you for your respond!

Comment: add sample code in codesandbox for debugging is better

Answer (score 0):

Add `^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$` regex in your onChange event input.

```
onChange(e){
    const re = /^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$/;
    if (e.target.value === '' || re.test(e.target.value)) {
       this.setState({value: e.target.value})
    }
}
```